# Why is the traditional character for 你 also 你 and not 儞 when the traditional character for 尔 is 爾?

Tags: glyph-origin, traditional-vs-simplified

I found an interesting question posted on [Reddit's /r/ChineseLanguage](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/): [If 你 is 亻（人） ＋ 尔 , but 尔’s tradicional version is 爾 , shouldn’t 你’s traditional version be 儞 ??](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/hpi6fr/if_%E4%BD%A0_is_%E4%BA%BB%E4%BA%BA_%E5%B0%94_but_%E5%B0%94s_tradicional_version_is_%E7%88%BE/)  I don't know the answer so I thought I'd re-ask it here.  Some answers given there were:

- [marktwainbrain](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/hpi6fr/if_%E4%BD%A0_is_%E4%BA%BB%E4%BA%BA_%E5%B0%94_but_%E5%B0%94s_tradicional_version_is_%E7%88%BE/fxray4a?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x): According to Pleco, 儞 does exist and it is an old variant of 你.
- [catoncurtain](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/hpi6fr/if_%E4%BD%A0_is_%E4%BA%BB%E4%BA%BA_%E5%B0%94_but_%E5%B0%94s_tradicional_version_is_%E7%88%BE/fxramld?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x): Well actually you are right, [儞](https://www.zdic.net/hant/%E5%84%9E)
- [CosmicBioHazard](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/hpi6fr/if_%E4%BD%A0_is_%E4%BA%BB%E4%BA%BA_%E5%B0%94_but_%E5%B0%94s_tradicional_version_is_%E7%88%BE/fxs05tz?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x): basically 儞 simplified down to 你 ages and ages before "simplified Chinese" was introduced.

I'm not sure if any of these are correct, although CosmicBioHazard's answer seems reasonable.  The Pleco entry is actually the CC-CEDICT entry:

> 儞 儞 [ni3] /old variant of 你[ni3]/

**Question**: Why is the traditional character for 你 also 你 and not 儞 when the traditional character for 尔 is 爾?

*Edit*: It was [brought to my attention](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/someone-seems-to-be-copy-pasting-question-titles-to-quora-without-attribution?noredirect=1#comment1144_1765) that Quora has a similar question: [Why do all of the Traditional Chinese standards use 你 (with the Simplified 尔) but keep 爾?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-all-of-the-Traditional-Chinese-standards-use-%E4%BD%A0-with-the-Simplified-%E5%B0%94-but-keep-%E7%88%BE?) likely posted recently (prior to this question).  I was not aware of this at the time of writing this question.

Comment: 康熙字典 had no entry for 儞 but 伱 while explained "伱...俗書作你". I doubt whether 儞 had been actually used in ancient publications or handwritten scripts or inscriptions etc. If anyone finds any source for ancient 儞 in actual use, please leave the source here. Thanks!

Comment: What's interesting. According to 康熙字典, 伱's origin glyph was [伲](http://dict.iguci.cn/kangxi/index/view/page/96/p/96/x/53/y/292) but not 儞, and there was a seal script to justify it from [傳抄古文字 海3.4](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/char?fontcode=83.EDB1).

Comment: Since I haven't seen any 儞 in ancient publications yet—please correct me if anyone finds the ancient source—I have a conjecture: 儞 might be the made-up one (no earlier before Qing dynasty I guess) resembling the 妳-嬭 pair that appeared in 康熙字典 both, while 伱/你 had been already widely used in novels in Ming dynasty like 西遊記.

Comment: @Stan 儞 is recorded to have occurred on 戰國 燕 potteryware as someone's name (kind of; it had an extra phonetic 厶 on the top right), as the name of the craftsman (高明 古陶文彙編 4.47). I don't think I can get a hold of this reference unfortunately, but what you should see is a mark which says 右宮儞 (see bjwb.bjd.com.cn/images/2020-05/28/23/23.pdf for what 右宮X means)

Comment: Regardless, the character 儞 was very uncommon, you can treat its appearance later as an unorthodox innovation. In order of innovation, the character representing a word meaning *you* is probably something like 爾 > 尔 > 你 > 儞. The Warring States 儞, I would treat as unrelated for now.

Comment: eh, an interesting question, but somewhat silly, because the simplified characters are based on the traditional and not vice-versa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the book 類篇　卷二十二 [(page 87 of the liked pdf)](https://archive.org/details/06052841.cn/page/n87/mode/1up), there was an entry:

> 伲儞你乃倚切汝也或作儞你你又乃里切文三重音一

that, **伲　儞　你** ・[these three characters are pronounced as] 乃倚切・[have the meaning of] 汝 (you)

the book “類篇” is edited between 1039-1066, in 宋 dynasty.

i would say that 儞 / 你 existed in the past, just not commonly used as 汝

have fun :)

[image]

Comment: I've been aware of this but I can't really find an example for the use of 儞 other than in a dictionary :(

Comment: @stan, search the kanripo.org, they’re occurrences that 儞 used as name :)

Answer (score 2):

> [儞](https://www.zdic.net/hant/%E5%84%9E)

> 古同“你”

> 「你 」的異體字

儞 is an archaic classical term that had been replaced by 你 in traditional character. ("long before simplified Chinese" was introduced." as one of your reference stated).

In other words, when they started simplifying traditional characters, the character 儞 did not exist in modern Chinese. It had been simplified to 你, and the simplified 儞 --> 你 had replaced 儞 and become the standard traditional character for 'you'

爾, on the other hand, is still being used in modern Chinese.

Since 尔 had already been used to simplify 爾, it was not used to simplify 你